# Get and execute function from key: value pair Object in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typeerror

I have a simple component that all it does is to render a list of resources. Those resources are fetched from a service that I'm calling inside this very Component. When that service is called, I broadcast a message to let other Components know that a resource was added to the database. I'm trying to execute a particular function when a particular message is broadcast.

```js
// service/service-list/service-list.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from '../service.model'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServiceApi } from '../service.api';
import { MessagingService } from 'src/app/messaging.service';
import { ServiceFunctionMaps } from '../service.function.maps.model';
import { ServiceFunction } from '../service.function.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-list',
  templateUrl: './service-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-list.component.css']
})
export class ServiceListComponent implements OnInit {

  allServices: Service[]
  functionMaps: ServiceFunctionMaps = {
    // serviceAdded: this.getAllServices
    serviceAdded: <ServiceFunction>this.getAllServices
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private api: ServiceApi, private msgService: MessagingService) {
    this.msgService.readMessage().subscribe(msg => {
      this.functionMaps[msg]()
      // The if statement works just fine
      // if (msg === 'serviceAdded') {
      //   this.getAllServices()
      // }
    })
    this.msgService.cleareMessage()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllServices()
  }

  private getAllServices() {
    this.api.fetchAllServices().subscribe(responseData => {
      this.allServices = responseData
    })
  }
}
```

```js
// service/service-function.ts
export interface ServiceFunction {
  (params?: string): void
  // (params?: string): Function
  // (params?: string): () => void
}
```

```js
// service/service-function-maps.model.ts
import { ServiceFunction } from './service-function.model';

export interface ServiceFunctionMaps {
  [key: string]: ServiceFunction
}
```

As you can see, I want to dynamically execute a function based on the broadcasted message. Right now code compiles but I get an error in the console like so...

```sh
core.js:6189 ERROR TypeError: this.functionMaps[msg] is not a function
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

How can I create an object of functions to be executed dynamically?

Comment: Why using an interface as the type for the function instead of a lambda type (such as described here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type) ?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to execute your functions from an object and not a component/service?

Comment: @RMo, sure. I'm broadcasting a message from other components when something happens, for instance, a new record got created in the database. In the other component I want to execute a specific function based on message broadcasted. I'm avoiding the use of `@Input()` and `Output()`

Comment: You are using a service with a public observable that your components can subscribe to. You could check the result using a `switch(msg) case 'service added': this.doSomething(); break;` calling a private method on success. So it's still not really clear to me why you want to use a map here.

Comment: You are right @RMo, I can do that with a `switch`, but you are looking at a small part of a full app. I don't know if you know running a func from a object is faster than a `switch` or ` if () {}`. https://jsperf.com/if-switch-lookup-table/10

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Two changes fixed the problem:

1. `bind(this)`

```js
  // I don't need the type interface
  functionMaps = {
    serviceAdded: this.getAllServices.bind(this)
  }
```

2. `if () {}`. Seems like when the Components loads the first time, it doesn't have the object declared.

```js
this.msgService.readMessage().subscribe(msg => {
  if(this.functionMaps[msg]){
    this.functionMaps[msg]();
  }
})
```